# How to continue the same action in NLA

Tags: nla-editor, actions

There are two actions. One of them is a simple movement along the axis, the other is a small rotation. If I copy the action, or set the number of repetitions to more than one - then they do not continue the movement, but start from the initial position, this applies to both movement and rotation. How to make the movement continue?

[image]

No matter how many tutorials I watch about blender, blender keeps reminding me that I don't know anything about blender.

Comment: I don't think that you can do that, but you can parent your object to an empty, then move and keyframe the empty where it is supposed to start the second action

Comment: @moonboots so NLA can work only with manually configured cycled loops? Actually, it is logical. A graph editor will cope better with this task.

Comment: [This video](https://youtu.be/UxdPtVAz6Do) is a pretty good introduction to the NLA and shows one way to break down an animation by imposing cycles onto free motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do a *Reapeat with Offset* in the *NLA*. Parenting your object to an empty may help you in that type of situation, you can move it to the new location in order to create the offset.

But you can give a *Cycles* modifier to your action in the *Graph Editor > N panel > Modifiers*, and in the modifier you can choose *After Mode > Repeat with Offset*, which will repeat the action but will consider the last transform (location, rotation or scale) of your object.